# Shadows doesn't work in layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, shadow

I have problem with shadows. In Android Studio preview shows:

[Editor preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8OCC.jpg)

but in emulator and in the phone I see:

[Emulator preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/She2t.jpg)

There is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".Profil"
android:background="@color/lightback"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/testFragmentu2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:translationZ="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"></FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:id="@+id/testFragmentu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:translationZ="0dp"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></FrameLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"

    android:translationZ="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Niestety, wszyscy mają partnerów na siłownię... :(" />


        <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I am trying to create 3 fragments. Two of them should appear from top when I click on an item of third fragment. But there is no shadow. I've set `translationZ` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Use CardView with elevation

Comment: On which android version you are testing?

Comment: API23. I don't want use CardView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shadows, you should use `elevation` like this :

```
app:elevation="10dp"
```

instead of `translationZ`

As mentioned in the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#elevation), `elevation` is "base z depth of the view" and this is a static variable, while `translationZ` is dynamic.

> elevation
>
> base z depth of the view.
>
> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp".

You should use `translationZ` for animations.

Comment: It works, thank you. But I had to change backgorund color to non transparent